# Central simple algebras give rise to algebraic groups

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups, division-algebras

Let $D$ be a central division algebra over a field $k$ of dimension $n^2$.  I have heard that the functor

$$R \mapsto (D \otimes_k R)^{\ast}$$

going from commutative $k$-algebras to groups is representable by an affine $k$-scheme $G$, and moreover that the group scheme $G$ is a connected, reductive group over $k$.  Where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, there is (almost) nothing special about $D$ being a central division algebra here. Let $F$ be a field, and let $A$ be a unital, associative $F$-algebra of finite dimension $n$. Then the functor

$$\mathrm{GL}_{1}(A) \colon \mathrm{Alg}_{F} \to \mathrm{Groups}, R \mapsto (A \otimes_{F} R)^{\times}$$

is an affine group scheme over $F$. The representing algebra is given by $B = S(A^{\ast})[1/N]$, where $A^{\ast}$ is the dual of $A$, $S(A^{\ast})$ is the symmetric algebra of $A^{\ast}$, and $N \colon A \to F$ is the norm map, considered as an element of $S^{n}(A^{\ast})$. The comultiplication is $c \colon B \to B \otimes_{F} B$ is induced by the map $A^{\ast} \to A^{\ast} \otimes_{F} A^{\ast}$ dual to the multiplication map $A \otimes_{F} A \to A$.

One specific case which you are almost certainly familiar with is the case $A = \mathrm{End}_{F}(V)$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$. In this case, $\mathrm{GL}_{1}(A)$ is just $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, the general linear group scheme associated to $V$. If $V = F^{n}$, then $\mathrm{GL}_{1}(A) = \mathrm{GL}_{n}$, and the representing algebra can be more explicitly identified as the polynomial ring over $F$ in $n^{2}$ variables $X_{ij}, 1 \leqslant i, j \leqslant n$, with the determinant of the matrix $X = (X_{ij})$ inverted.

It depends on what details you're looking for, but a good reference for this is Chapters VI and VII of [The Book of Involutions](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~rost/BoI.html) by Knus, Merkurjev, Rost, and Tignol. For instance, it is also proved, or at least mentioned, that $\mathrm{GL}_{1}(A)$ is connected and smooth. It is also proved that $H^{1}(F, \mathrm{GL}_{1}(A)) = 1$, which is the most general formulation of Hilbert's Theorem 90 that I am aware of. It does not mention whether $\mathrm{GL}_{1}(A)$ is reductive in general (this is my "almost" caveat above), but perhaps it can be deduced in your specific case from other statements available in the book.

Comment: D a central division algebra implies GL_1(D) is reductive (proof: after passing to algebraic closure, D becomes a matrix algebra and so GL_1(D) becomes the general linear group). In the generality you mention, GL_1(A) is not always reductive (e.g. A=k[x]/(x^2))